# Excel 2007 VBA win32 dll function weird behavior?

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, dll, gdi

Just for the fun of it I wanted to call a GDI (win32) drawing function from excel-vba. Following are my dll function declarations. All these are imported from win32.

```
Public Declare Function GetDC _
Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal handle As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function MoveToEx _
Lib "gdi32.dll" _
(ByVal handle As Long, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal lppoint As Long) As Integer

Public Declare Function LineTo _
Lib "gdi32.dll" _
(ByVal handle As Long, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer

Public Declare Function ReleaseDC _
Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Integer

Public Declare Function GetSystemMetrics _
Lib "user32.dll" _
(ByVal i As Integer) As Integer
```

The result I wish to get is a line from upper left corner of the screen to lower right corner. Following code gives the required result.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dc As Long

    dc = GetDC(0)
    screenX = GetSystemMetrics(0)
    screenY = GetSystemMetrics(1)
    MoveToEx dc, 0, 0, 0
    LineTo dc, screenX, screenY

    ReleaseDC 0, dc
End Sub
```

But the problem is following code doesn't do anything. Why?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dc As Long
    Dim screenX, screenY As Integer

    dc = GetDC(0)
    screenX = GetSystemMetrics(0)
    screenY = GetSystemMetrics(1)
    MoveToEx dc, 0, 0, 0
    LineTo dc, screenX, screenY

    ReleaseDC 0, dc
End Sub
```

The only difference is in the second code, third line declares the variables `screenX` and `screenY` and in the first code, they aren't declared. Can anyone please explain what's going on?

Comment: `Integer` is 16 bits wide in VBA. You mean `Long`.

Comment: Well, I don't even know what the so-called erratic behaviour is. Do you realise that you can't expect to just paint on `GetDC(0)`?

Answer (score 2):

As well as all the mis-declarations of variables, leading to the un-intended use of variants, I can see a couple more problems:

1. You use `Integer` in a number of the API calls. But in VBA `Integer` is a signed 16 bit type. All the uses of `Integer` in your `Declare` statements should instead be `Long`, a signed 32 bit integer.
2. You are drawing to the screen DC. You aren't supposed to do this. It will have un-predicatable results. The screen is owned by the system and you should not draw on that DC. You'll need to find another way to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim screenX As Integer
Dim screenY As Integer
```

because `Dim screenX, screenY As Integer` is actually equivalent to:

```
Dim screenX As Variant
Dim screenY As Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not have variable declaration set to required. If you did, you would see an

```
Option Explicit
```

at the top of each module.

Since you don't have it, both `screenX` and `screenY` are defaulting to variants in your first code sample.

In the second sample, you are setting `screenX` to be a variant, which accommodates any data type, but you are explicitly setting `screenY` as an integer, and an integer isn't the right data type for what you are doing.

EDIT: Per David's answer, you need longs and not integers.

NOTE: be careful with variants, as they can introduce weird, hard to find bugs. An integer is obviously not the right type, but you should figure out what data type you need and explicitly declare it.